# How to keep only those archivelogs that are created after a latest db backup in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, rman, archive-log

I am little confused with oracle db backup.
I have configured my Oracle 11G DB with ARCHIVELOG in Fast Recovery Area (NFS mount).

I only need latest backup to restore in case of failure, but no point-in-time recovery is needed. So, I only need to have backup of control files, SP files, DB files, Redo files and archive logs (which are created after my latest DB file backup) and I want to use the same Fast Recovery Area for my DB backups.

I have two questions actually:

- I don't understand what does it mean by backup of archive log, as the archivelog itself is backup of redo files (old files) and
  which I'm already keeping in NFS. So, does backing up archivelog
  actually do double backup and as in my case, the backup location is
  FRA, will it do backup to FRA again?
- How to set the correct retention policy to be able to keep only the archive logs that are created after my latest DB backup.